# What are the extraneous numbers appearing on the 'Questions that may already have your answer' feature?

Tags: support, asking-questions

When posting a new question, in the 'Questions that may already have your answer' section the question titles have an integer attached to the actual title.

I've attached screenshots to clarify:

[image]

Notice the 1,2,3 next to the titles. What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 5):

Those numbers tell you how many answers the question has. If you hover over it (as with many other things on this site), it tells you what it means.